# Having problems accessing tables with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having a strange problem with the php mysqli extension. On my local LAMP installation everything works fine.

After testing my site in the final production environment, I'm getting strange errors.

This is an excerpt out of my site internal SQL logfile:

```
[SUCCESS] SELECT * FROM `tbl1` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 20;
[ERROR]   SELECT * FROM `tbl1` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 20; 
          (Table 'dbname.tbl1' doesn't exist)
[SUCCESS] SELECT * FROM `tbl1` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 20;
[SUCCESS] SELECT * FROM `tbl1` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 20;
```

For testing purposes, I executed the same query four times in one function. Three out of four times the query succeeded. The failed query returns an error: Table 'dbname.tbl1' doesn't exist.

This problem appears always with different tables and in different functions. Sometimes *tbl1* is missing, after hitting F5 *tbl2* seems to be missing...

There seems to be a problem with my server settings since the queries always work in my local dev environment but only *sometimes* in the production environment.

Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

**Edit:** What I forgot to mention: When switching to the normal *mysql* php extension everything works fine. It really seems to be a problem with *mysqli*.

Comment: Is your database-name actually "dbname" ? Do you have more then one database? Could you have a function / file that uses a wrong database-connection? I think your best shot is to find out if there is a correlation between the errors and when / where / why the query is run.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My database is not called _dbname_. I just tried to simlipfy the problem description here. Since the application uses one single db interface class and db config I don't think it's possible that there is any function/file with a wrong db connection. A correlation is hard to find since the errors really seem to appear completely random!

Comment: I understood your database isn't called _exactly_ dbname, I just wanted to know if the mentioned string "dbname" is the same as the name of your database. If your database is called `dbnameA` and it says `dbnameB` that's an obvious reason why the table might not be found :). For database-connection: could there be a test-connection hanging around somewhere?

Comment: Can't you gather some relevant debugging info in case of error occurred?

Comment: can you show your connect query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

There was something wrong with my mysql-proxy setup. It sometimes lost the connection to the backend server. This was causing the *table not found* error.

Sorry for bothering and thanks to everyone that tried to help!

Have a nice day.